# how to join three tables in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to join three tables in laravel and to display the joined items.But it doesn't works properly.Some values are missing.when i am displaying a field in category(eg:categoryid) it doen't shows the entire row values and some column fields are missing.So please help me to correct it.

```
$products = DB::table('categories')
        ->leftjoin('subcategories', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
        ->leftjoin('products', 'products.subcat_id', '=', 'subcategories.subcat_id')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: You are not getting record of categories table or  subcategories table ?

Comment: Some datas in category table are missing

Comment: you should have used Model. When you have relation in Model, you dont need to manually join them in your query anymore no matter how deep or how many the join were

Answer (score 0):

use the Eloquent maybe cleaner. below is the example

```
class Category
{
     ...
     ...
   // i assume your category primary key is `id`
     public function subs()
     {
          return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'category_id');
     }
}


class SubCategory
{
     ...
     ...
    // i assume your subs category primary key is `id`
     public function products()
     {
          return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'subcat_id');
     }
}


class Product
{
     //
}
```

if using eloquent

```
$results = Category::query()->with('subs.products')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = DB::table('categories')
    ->join('subcategories', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
    ->join('products', 'products.subcat_id', '=', 'subcategories.subcat_id')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Try Inner Join and when you are fetching data you have the same column name I believe that's why it doesn't recognize it try to specify the value of your columns.
Like: select('products.name','subcategories.name')